# Install bpy - Cmake Error

Tags: python, linux

I want to install bpy on virtual env of python 3.7.11.
OS: Ubuntu 20.04

Error Message:
Could NOT find PythonLibsUnix (missing: PYTHON_LIBRARY PYTHON_LIBPATH
PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR PYTHON_INCLUDE_CONFIG_DIR)

Any ideas how fix it ?

Thank you!

Comment: a similar SO threat https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34064313/unable-to-build-blender

Comment: this comment https://github.com/spillai/numpy-opencv-converter/issues/6#issuecomment-439762880 pointed out that this is probably configuration cmakes needs not blender specifically, more docs here https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/module/FindPython.html

Comment: also semi relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60557690/cmake-is-looking-for-python-on-the-wrong-folder

Answer (score 1):

### (optional) use a specific python version from source

If you need to compile CPython from source, here is a tldr.

This is a very common download, extract, configure, make, make-install process; but we need to enable a couple CPython configuration flags for sure. ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26657830/1695680

```
$ wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.9/Python-3.9.9.tar.xz
$ unar Python-3.9.9.tar.xz
$ (cd Python-3.9.9.tar.xz; ./configure --enable-optimizations --enable-shared --prefix=$PWD/../python_3.9.9/; echo$?)
$ (cd Python-3.9.9.tar.xz; make; echo $?)
$ (cd Python-3.9.9.tar.xz; make install; echo $?)
```

### Configure CMake to "find" our python

returning to our blender make/cmake

```
# for using `make` in the blender folder, 
# add the BUILD_CMAKE_ARGS=-DPYTHON_ROOT_DIR argument

$ BUILD_CMAKE_ARGS=-DPYTHON_ROOT_DIR=$PWD/python_3.9.9/ make
```

otherwise, if using cmake directly use `cmake -DPYTHON_ROOT_DIR=$PWD/python_3.9.9/` normally